# Typo3 9.x RTE conf

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-9.x

Is there a way to configure RTE in Typo3 9.3? 
I tried old config which was perfectly fine in 7 and 8 versions but not in 9:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/8.7.1/DefaultConfigurations/Minimal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rtehtmlarea is not part of TYPO3 anymore in version 9 and was superseded by CKEditor in TYPO3 version 8.

Although this article about the [configuration of CKEditor in TYPO3](https://usetypo3.com/ckeditor.html) is written for version 8 it should be still valid for version 9 and will point you in the right direction.

Furthermore the [documentation of CKEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/) itself could help